# React app show azure devops build/tag version

Tags: reactjs, azure

How to add build/tag version to UI (ReactJS) from CI/CD? I already try to add some env variable to pipeline (`REACT_APP_VERSION: $(major).$(minor)$(Rev:.r)`) but it's not working properly shows: `1.1$(Rev:.r)`

Comment: When is the env file being populated from? Please list out in more detail what you have tried to avoid having people suggest things you've already tried. My idea would be to write the tag to a file that is created during the pipeline then export this as part of the build artifact. Your application would then read this file in to get the value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved by this pipeline yml config:

```
variables:
   REACT_APP_VERSION: $(Build.BuildNumber)

name: $(major).$(minor)$(Rev:.r)
```